# jQuery hiding dropdown after animation

Tags: jquery, animation, drop-down-menu, queue, hide

I'm trying to solve a problem here.

The following jQuery script is for a dropdown menu of mine.

all the following code works good for me, except there's one hitch i've run into.

If I click on one of the .drop class 'a' links to get my dropdown, it comes down with all the following animations listed in the code below. but unfortunately, when I click on another .drop class 'a' link, the other dropdown doesn't go away.

I've tried using   `$("ul.dropdown").hide();` but this cancels out the animation of `if(theDropState){ .. }` by making it disappear instantly.

Can anybody help me find a solution for making it hide itself, but AFTER the `if(theDropState){ .. }` animation is done?

I've tried putting `$("ul.dropdown").hide();` in a **callback** function, but that didn't work either.

```
    $(".drop").click(function(event) {
  var theDrop = $(this).next("ul.dropdown");
  theDropState = theDrop.is(':visible');

  if(theDropState){ 
    theDrop.stop(true,true).animate({ height: 'hide' }, '200'); 
    $('#header').stop(true,true).animate({ height: '50px' }, '200', function(){
          $("ul.dropdown").hide();
    });
  }
  else if(!theDropState){
    theDrop.stop(true,true).animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 'show' }, '200') 
    $('#header').stop(true,true).animate({ height: '100px' }, '200') 
  }
```

any and all help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback

```
$('#foo').animate({height: '200px'}, 200, function(){ /*  do stuff */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) can get a **callback** function once it is done.
just pass it whatever you want to execute on callback.

```
.animate({ height: '50px' }, '200', function() {
  // do stuff here 
 });
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using a callback and in the edited post I have a live version of how that works - it's very buggy